# Easiest way to solder connections to all the legs on a surface-mount chip?

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, tqfp

Recently, I went through the process of soldering wires onto the legs of a TQFP chip (~0.8mm pitch) which has already been mounted on a PCB. This is a project where I am doing some modifications to the original hardware, so I don't have the ability to change the PCB design at all. I was curious if there was any way to more quickly attach connections to this chip - perhaps some sort of socket that sits on top of the chip? Really, is there any way to make connections to the legs of the chip other than painstakingly soldering individual wires?

Comment: You stand to damage the IC by soldering directly to the pin. Instead, remove the insulation from a circuit path on the PCB relatively close to the IC and solder wire onto the PCB path.

Comment: Also, what IC are you using? Can you post an image or datasheet link?

Comment: Google searched for "QFP clamp"; found this: http://www.adapters.com/prod_serv/em_clip.htm Not sure of this company or how "legit" they are, but perhaps it will start you down a road.

Comment: @Shabab - No datasheet available, unfortunately. I'm working with CNT-NUS, a chip inside all Nintendo 64 controllers. Pinout is here, if you're interested: http://shockslayer.com/IC/finishedcontrollerchipguide.png

Answer (score 1):

[3M Z-Axis tape](http://products3.3m.com/catalog/ca/en001/architecture_construction/-/node_GSZPBZC7M5be/root_VJ3G0N3T7Ngv/vroot_8HML2LL1M1ge/gvel_QRVQ181QXMgl/theme_ca_en_archconstruction_3_0/command_AbcPageHandler/output_html%5B) is conductive only through the plane; across the plane it is insulating. You could place a strip across the legs of the package and then press wires to the other side of the tape.

[Sparkfun demostration video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3SPijvXtew#t=64)

Answer (score 0):

You can use wire #30. It is easy to solder and does not need much heat

Comment: Also known as "wire-wrap" wire, because it was commonly used for wire-wrapping back in the day when that technology was popular.  I use it both for repair and building prototypes.

Comment: Most likely the asker already does as well.